# FDT: Do Haxe projects in 5.5 have full code complete intellisense support for AS3 and other targets ?

Tags: intellisense, haxe, fdt

I can tell this version for haxe is quite a bit better but I noticed when trying to get code hinting or intellisense on AS3 classes I don't get any public methods showing up or variables for that matter?

Is this not yet supported or is there something I have to do too configure this?

here is an example of me trying to use the drawing api and not getting anything useful [image]

Comment: Are you using 2.09? Please confirm in Preferences>Haxe>Haxe SDK

Comment: Yes I'm using 2.09 and I also checked my Flash settings to make sure the ASO path was set.

Comment: Is this an existing project or a new one from scratch (template)? You may be missing some default Type info generated by the compiler. Try a hello world with a new project, using a template.

Comment: This was an existing project I created in another IDE but in order to get it into FDT I basically "created new" project but then nixed the src directory and used an existing hxml.

Comment: creating a new project from scratch with hello world did work and intellisense works.

Comment: is there a way for me to fix this within the other project or is the best option to just create new and the move my class files over ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FDT's Haxe autocompletion is completely dependent on the Haxe compiler (or Auto Completion server if you're using that). If the compiler does not 'see' your file then there will be no autocomplete.

There are numerous things that are going on; however, here are a few:

### The basic Types might be missing.

You'll need to clean or get the compiler to do a full build to create these files again.

[image]

### The class you're editing is not being compiled.

Because autocompletion is based on the compiler, if the file is not connected to the compiler you won't get anything. To do this, you'll need to make sure that your project is being built from your .HXML file and that the file you're editing is somehow connected (e.g. imported or instanciated at some point in your application) to your 'Main' class.

Matt, the 2nd issue is probably what is happening to you. Make sure it's being built correctly from your HXML file and it's connected to your 'Main' class. Otherwise moving over the files from your old project to one that is created in FDT, is the sure fire way to fix it.

Comment: Yep ... creating a new project and just moving the files is the best way to go.